# IntelliJ IDEA Java formatter, how to not allow blank lines after opening braces?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've searched existing questions and IDEA formatter options but to no avail, I can not for the life of me figure out how to prevent these sorts of blank lines after the braces:

```
public void foo() {

   int x = 0;
   if {

      int y = 0;
   }
}
```

I know I can get rid of ALL blank lines in the code body by specifying maximum lines in "code" to be 0 but that's not what I want.

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the `if`, but for the method body, it might be:

> Preferences > Editor > Code Style > Java > Blank Lines > Before method body > 1

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I already have that set but it doesn't remove the blank lines already in the codebase.  I need a maximum of zero.

Answer (score 0):

in your IDE `file->settings->code style->java`. then select `Blank Lines` tab and change **Before Method Body**.